# How to call the correct overloaded function at runtime?

Tags: c#, reflection

How do I call the correct overloaded function given a reference to an object based on the actual type of the object. For example...

```
class Test
{
    object o1 = new object();
    object o2 = new string("ABCD");
    MyToString(o1);
    MyToString(o2);//I want this to call the second overloaded function


    void MyToString(object o)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyToString(object) called.");
    }

    void MyToString(string str)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyToString(string) called.");
    }
}
```

what I mean is there a better option than the following?

```
if(typeof(o) == typeof(string))
{
    MyToString((string)o);
}
else
{
    MyToString(o);
}
```

May be this can be done using reflection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok as soon as I hit post I remembered this can indeed be done using reflection...

```
var methInfo = typeof(Test).GetMethod("MyToString", new Type[] {o.GetType()});
methInfo.Invoke(this, new object[] {o});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use ternary operators to code this using a single clean line of code:

```
MyToString(o is string ? (string)o : o);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a toString() function in the actual object itself? That way you can call myObj.toString() and the relative output is given.  Then you don't have to do any comparisons.

Comment: This is just an example demonstrating my actual problem.